# Replace words within a string field if the word starts with specific characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, replace

I want to be able to replace all instances of words (space or line-break delineated), within a string field, which start with a given set of characters, with a different single word. So any word starting with the given characters would be replaced by the same word.

The specific case I'm trying to deal with is that I am looking at an audit log of SQL run by the scheduler server. Our code is written using variables "{TempTable}" which, when run, resolves to something like "dbo.tmp1826_15712940", indicating it's a temporary table to be imported into table "dbo.tb1826". Everything after the underscore is a unique identifier which I want to remove, leaving just the "dbo.tmp1826".

I can't rely on that identifier to be the same length (though it will always be numeric) and the character after the identifier or before "dbo." may be a either a space or a line break. The 1826 is just an example and could be any positive integer. The word I want to replace may occur multiple times in a string. The system uses SQL Server, I think the 2017 version.

So

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tmp1234_12345678 WHERE <stuff>
SELECT * FROM dbo.tmp5678_56789012 WHERE <thingummybobs>
```

would become

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tmp1234 WHERE <stuff>
SELECT * FROM dbo.tmp5678 WHERE <thingummybobs>
```

Comment: T-SQL is not your "friend" for such a task; use a language that support pattern replacement.

Answer (score 1):

A few ways using t-sql I can think of, probably the cleanest would be

```
declare @string Varchar(20) = 'dbo.tmp1234_12345678';
select Left(@string, Len(@string) - PatIndex('%[^0-9]%', Reverse(@String)));
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, TSQL/SQL Server is not the optimal tool for this, but sometimes we're stuck having to use suboptimal solutions.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (String VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Table (String) VALUES 
('SELECT * FROM dbo.tmp1234_12345678 WHERE dbo.tmp1234_12345678 AND dbo.tmp1234_12345678'),
('SELECT * FROM dbo.tmp5678_56789012 WHERE <thingummybobs>');
```

I modified your data a little, just to demonstrate that this would replace all occurrences of the string.

```
SELECT *, PATINDEX('%dbo.tmp%', String) AS StringStart, CHARINDEX(' ',String,PATINDEX('%dbo.tmp%', String)) AS StringEnd,
SUBSTRING(String,PATINDEX('%dbo.tmp%', String),CHARINDEX(' ',String,PATINDEX('%dbo.tmp%', String))-PATINDEX('%dbo.tmp%', String)) AS StringToReplace,
SUBSTRING(String,PATINDEX('%dbo.tmp%', String),CHARINDEX('_',String,PATINDEX('%dbo.tmp%', String))-PATINDEX('%dbo.tmp%', String)) AS StringToWith,
REPLACE(String,SUBSTRING(String,PATINDEX('%dbo.tmp%', String),CHARINDEX(' ',String,PATINDEX('%dbo.tmp%', String))-PATINDEX('%dbo.tmp%', String)),SUBSTRING(String,PATINDEX('%dbo.tmp%', String),CHARINDEX('_',String,PATINDEX('%dbo.tmp%', String))-PATINDEX('%dbo.tmp%', String))) AS Replaced
  FROM @Table;
```

`PATINDEX` returns the first position of the pattern within the string, with % being the wild card character. `CHARINDEX` returns the first position of the character within the string. In this case we're using the optional 3rd parameter of `CHARINDEX` to designate a start position. `SUBSTRING` returns the string between the start and length positions specified.

| String | StringStart | StringEnd | StringToReplace | StringToReplaceWith | Replaced |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SELECT * FROM dbo.tmp1234_12345678 WHERE dbo.tmp1234_12345678 AND dbo.tmp1234_12345678 | 15 | 35 | dbo.tmp1234_12345678 | dbo.tmp1234 | SELECT * FROM dbo.tmp1234 WHERE dbo.tmp1234 AND dbo.tmp1234 |
| SELECT * FROM dbo.tmp5678_56789012 WHERE | 15 | 35 | dbo.tmp5678_56789012 | dbo.tmp5678 | SELECT * FROM dbo.tmp5678 WHERE |

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
create table dbo.tmp123_15712940(
id int
)

create table dbo.tmp2345_15712940(
id int
)

create table dbo.tmp67_15712940(
id int
)

declare @sql varchar(max) = ''
declare @sql2 varchar(max) = ''

select distinct @sql=string_agg(cast('insert into tbl
select ''' + TABLE_NAME + '''' as varchar(max)), char(10))
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME like 'tmp%'

create table dbo.tbl (
tbl varchar(100)
)

exec(@sql)

select @sql2=string_agg(cast('EXEC sp_rename ''' + tbl + ''',''' + substring(tbl,1,CHARINDEX('_',tbl)-1) + '''' as varchar(max)), char(10))
from dbo.tbl

exec(@sql2)

drop table dbo.tbl
```